# Need help modeling a relation between images and some classes that use them

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I have an `Image` aggregate, which has 3 properties: content, filename (as key) and mimetype.

Then I have one `Company` aggregate with the photos and logo properties.

Those properties hold a filename (the image's key) as value, pointing thus to the `Image`.

There are some other aggregates using images this way.

The thing is, I need the image to be used just once in the whole system. If I use the image in one company, it cannot be used in another. If I use it as a logo, it cannot be used as a photo, an so on.

All solutions I tried smells a lot, so maybe some of you can bring some ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: I would go with that relationship / restriction being represented on the `Image` aggregate.  Either `IsAssigned` (very generic) or `AssignedOwnerType` / `AssignedOwnerId`.

Comment: Oh, great! I had thought about that but now that you say the same gives me more confidence! I was also thinking on creating a `Protector` class so I can ask if someone is using the image, and the registered objects can answer by yes or no. That way I am not coupled to classes using the images neither the way they are using it (logo, photo, whatever), I just ask for a confirmation. What do you think about that?

Comment: Because you put domain-driven design tag, you should return to your domain experts. DDD prior strategic patterns (ubiquitous language, context map, domain and bounded context design) over tactic patterns (the aggregates, entities and value objects design).

Comment: What if it's just me? I have no domain experts but me haha, what can I ask myself to find the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the notification message for your answer. 
Don't you have any "client" ? If you cannot obtain a domain expert knowledge, you can be the domain expert but it demands a lot of document efforts.

Comment: It’s just me. Help me to find the way to solve this situation. How should I think around this. I have the images situation, how can I find the answer to that in my domain? I know I have some images and those can only be used once, now I have to translate that to code, because you last message was too pessimistic, with no value added 

Comment: @k-ter, yes... if the rule can be encapsulated within the `Image` aggregate adequately then no reason to apply the same logic to different aggregates.  However, once that changes and on image can be assigned to more than one aggregate things may need to change slightly.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Eben Roux's commentary is interesting.

In addition, if you work in Domain-Driven Design and depending on the context, you can add a class for each type of photo (using inheritance) or using an ImageType.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I've answered in the comments above, can you contribute there?

Comment: Hi, no problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest introducing the concept of an `ImageSlot` which simplifies complex AR-image relationships.

Now there's 2 rules you want to be strongly consistent:

- a) An image slot should not be used more than once.
- b) An image should not be used more than once.

Solutions:

1. Inverse relationship and model it on the `Image` side so that the `Image` refers to the slot. This ensures to protect **a)**, but you'd need a unique constraint on the `slotId` to protect **b)**.
2. Model a bi-directional relationship. With optimistic locking this would ensure TXs using the same images & slots would conflict.

[image]

Upon the creation of aggregates that requires you'd also allocate them new slots.

Code for using an image in a given slot at the service layer may look like:

```
class Service {
    //Assume transactional
    changeImage(slotId, imageId) {
       slot = imageSlotRepository.slotOfId(slotId);
       image = imageRepository.imageOfId(imageId);

       if (image.used()) {
          currentSlot = imageSlotRepository.slotOfId(image.slotId());
          currentSlot.clear();
          image.removeFrom(currentSlot);
       }

       if (!slot.isEmpty()) {
           currentImage = imageRepository.imageOfId(slot.imageId());
           slot.clear();
           currentImage.removeFrom(slot);
       }

       slot.changeImage(image); // detects same slot usage concurrency
       image.useIn(slot); // detects same image usage concurrency
    }
}


class ImageSlot {
    private id;
    private imageId;

    changeImage(newImage) {
        this.imageId = newImage.id();
    }
    clear() {
        this.imageId = null;
    }
    used() { return this.imageId != null }
}

class Image {
    private id;
    private slotId;

    // preconditions ensure the inverse relation has been set
    removeFrom(slot) {
        if (slotId != slot.id) throw wrong slot;
        if (slot.imageId() != null) throw not empty;

        this.slotId = null;
    }
    useIn(slot) {
        if (slot.id() !== this.slotId) throw wrong slot;

        this.slotId = slot.id();
    }
}
```

DDD is all about those conceptual "breakthroughs". You didin't have the concept of an `ImageSlot` before and perhaps that's your salvation... or perhaps not ;)